# Cold start for Node.js

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have experience working with AWS Lambda and on my previous job we were able to have a neglectable cold start time for our use case (99% of cold start < 500 ms). Now I am working for a new company with similar use case, but they selected GCP as the main cloud platform.

By investigating Google Cloud functions it seems that the effective cold start for Google Cloud Functions are 5+ times longer than Lambda (for node.js) which might turn cloud functions not suitable for User facing APIs, unfortunately.

Is there anything in the pipeline to make Cloud Functions cold start as short (or shorter) than the one seen for AWS Lambda?

Regards

Comment: Without a lot more information it's not really possible to answer this question. It depends on a lot of factors. There's a good video about optimizing cold starts here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOXrwFqR6kY. Something there might work?

Comment: Did you have a look here? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances#idle_instances_and_minimizing_cold_starts

Comment: @jfbaro Are you using firestore too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is something in the pipeline. They talked on it on the last Google IO Firebase QA. I can remember watching it. Here is a link to that question and answer: https://youtu.be/3BMNzY_ljSw?t=865

No one can tell now when it will come to Firebase but I hope soon :)

**UPDATE**

You can check it now in the [releas note](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#min-max-instances) ;)

```js
exports.getAutocompleteResponse = functions
    .runWith({
      // Keep 5 instances warm for this latency-critical function
      minInstances: 5,
    })
    .https.onCall((data, context) => {
      // Autocomplete a user's search term
    });
```

Comment: That's great news Tarik! Thank you so much!!